# How to pass html to sub-template in dust.js

Tags: html, dust.js

In my `dust` file I have the following line...

```
{>"form-row-text-input" nLabel="My name is {name}" nValue=name /}
```

I am passing a sub-template `name` which is a string (first name and last name). I want to style the name so I was thinking of adding a span tag. However, I can't seem to do that.

I tried setting name as `<span class="name">name variable</span>` and then passing that through the template but it only gets interpreted as a string. I've tried a few combinations but they don't work.

Is there any way to surround the sub-template within html tags inside of `nLabel`?